# Can't compile code with CVC4 C++ API

Tags: c++, g++, smt, cvc4

I am just trying to compile this file `helloworld.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cvc4/cvc4.h>
using namespace CVC4;
int main() {
        ExprManager em;
        Expr helloworld = em.mkVar("Hello World!", em.booleanType());
        SmtEngine smt(&em);
        std::cout << helloworld << " is " << smt.query(helloworld) << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

using `g++ helloworld.cpp -lcvc4 -o helloworld -lcvc4 -Wno-deprecated`. But it is giving me this error

```
/tmp/cc9SFpL4.o: In function `main':
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0xac): undefined reference to `CVC4::ExprManager::mkVar(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, CVC4::Type, unsigned int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Help!

I have installed `CVC4` adding repo link in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and then calling `sudo apt-get install cvc4 libcvc4-dev libcvc4parser-dev`.

EDIT: I mistyped `g++ helloworld.cpp -lcvc4 ...` I used `g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld -lcvc4 -Wno-deprecated`. Actually I used all combinations, permutations.

Comment: Did you do `sudo apt-get update` before the install? Just installed CVC4 on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS using the repository and the example worked.

Comment: Try `g++ helloworld.cpp -Wno-deprecated -o helloworld -lcvc4`.  On some systems the `-l` linker flags need to appear last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the OP's environment.  Both r4C9rAyrd6A1 and I were able to compile the example on our local machines.  The specific issue might have been that the OP's compiler wanted the `-lcvc4` linker flag after the other flags, e.g. `g++ helloworld.cpp -Wno-deprecated -o helloworld -lcvc4` as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: you're right. I ran the same thing on WSL and it worked. so yea, it seems to be a problem with my environment. anyway thanks. :)

Comment: Ah, I see your edit now.  Great that you got it working.